# Symfony remove file after download

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony application where users can crop images with. After someone has downloaded the cropped image I want the application to remove it from the server.

I currently have this controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/download/{crop_id}",
 *      name="download_cropped",
 *      options={"expose"=true}
 * )
 *
 * @ParamConverter(
 *      "crop",
 *      class="WebwijsCropperBundle:Crop",
 *      options={"id" = "crop_id"}
 * )
 *
 */
public function downloadAction(Crop $crop)
{
    $dir = $this->container->getParameter('image.cropped.dir');
    return new BinaryFileResponse($dir . '/' . $crop->getCroppedFile());
}
```

I created this EventListener where I want to remove the image after the response is sent. This Listener will be triggered after every response.

So how do I get the information that I need to know if the response comes from the correct controller action. And how can I get the crop_id parameter so I know which file to remove?

```
class FileRemovalListener
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        // what do i have to do here to know 
        // from which controller action the response comes?

    }
}
```

This is the service definition in services.yml

```
WebwijsCropperBundle\EventListener\FileRemovalListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onKernelTerminate }
```

Comment: create a new deleteAction. then define redirect route to that deleteAction after downloading

Comment: I would go with something like:

If the user clicks the download button, you send ajax call to some kind of `deleteAction` and you forward the id 

or 

you give a lifetime to all cropped images images and you have a cron job that would delete all images that have expired every 15 minutes or something like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you only want to remove the file, try this:

```
public function downloadAction(Crop $crop)
{
    $dir = $this->container->getParameter('image.cropped.dir');
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($dir . '/' . $crop->getCroppedFile());

    $response->deleteFileAfterSend(true);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me. I also need to delete the entity but I can do that before the response is sent. I will try if this works for me and then mark your answer as correct!

Comment: It took a while, I was on vacation. Works like a charm!

Comment: Wow... Works like a dream. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
deleteFileAfterSend(bool $shouldDelete)
```

If this is set to true, the file will be unlinked after the request is sent. 
Note: If the X-Sendfile header is used, the deleteFileAfterSend setting will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just a precision about the function "deleteFileAfterSend(bool $bool)". As symfony documentation said *"(...)note that this will not work when the X-Sendfile header is set."*.
See : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files.
Then you can do something like this for delete a file after response sending :

```
$zipName = 'downloads/' . uniqid().'.zip';
$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->headers->set(...);

return $response->setCallBack(function () use($zipName) {
    readfile($zipName);
    $filesystem = new Filesystem();
    try {
       $filesystem->remove($zipName);
    } catch (IOExceptionInterface $exception) {
        echo "Cannot delete the zip file : ". $zipName;
    }
});
```